# Make MotionLayout Transition to have a constant speed

Tags: android, android-animation, android-motionlayout

How can I make my automatic transition to have a **constant speed**?
It always starts slowly and speeds up as it progress, then it slows down when is about to finish the transition, I want the speed to be the same from the beginning and until the end.

```
<Transition
    app:duration="@integer/long_duration"
    app:autoTransition="animateToEnd"
    app:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
    app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start">

    <KeyFrameSet>
        <KeyAttribute
            app:motionTarget="@id/animated_view"
            android:alpha="1" />
    </KeyFrameSet>
</Transition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `motionInterpolator` property of your `Transition`. Just set it to "linear"

```
<Transition
    app:duration="@integer/long_duration"
    app:autoTransition="animateToEnd"
    app:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
    app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"

    app:motionInterpolator="linear"> <!-- this is the trick -->

    <KeyFrameSet>
        <KeyAttribute
            app:motionTarget="@id/animated_view"
            android:alpha="1" />
    </KeyFrameSet>
</Transition>
```

Comment: This is correct, also, while I was trying to figure this I decided to try using the animation method that every view provides and you can also make the initial and end speed of the animation to be constant, basically: 

view.animate().interpolator = LinearInterpolator()